# Pay Pal Mass Pay IPN - Payment(batch) Status and single payment Status

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, masspay

We are sending payouts to our users with the MassPay API.
Our system works in a way that each MassPay batch includes only a single payment.

Our problem is that its not entirely clear how the MassPay IPN statuses work.

The PayPal docs say that there are 3 types of IPNs - Failed, Processed and Completed.

What I don't understand is which status combinations of payment_status and status1 are possible:

1. Can an IPN return (`payment_status = DENIED` and `status1 = Completed`)?
2. Will an IPN with `status1 = FAILED` or `BLOCKED` always have a `payment_status = DENIED` and vice versa?
3. Will a (`payment_status = PROCESSED and status1 = COMPLETED`) always come before an IPN with (`payment_status = COMPLETED and status1 = COMPLETED`)? If yes, is it enough to only check for (`payment_status = COMPLETED and status1 = COMPLETED`) to mark the payout as 'success' on our system?
4. Will an IPN with`status1 = REVERSED or RETURNED` always have `payment_status = COMPLETED`?
5. Will an IPN with `status1 = PENDING` always have a `payment_status = PROCESSED`?

To be more specific, it would help to know which of the payment_status and status1 combinations are even possible and whats the meaning of each possible status pair?

please see attached table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yknf.jpg)

Here is the table in text:

```
payment_status    status1      Is Combination Possible?    Meaning

Processed     Blocked        ?   
Processed     Pending        ?
Processed     Unclaimed    YES
Processed     Reversed    ?
Processed     Completed    YES             Will this always have COMPLETED+COMPLETED afterwards?
Processed     Failed        ?
Processed     Returned    ?

Denied         Blocked        ?   
Denied         Pending        ?
Denied         Unclaimed    ?
Denied         Reversed    ?
Denied         Completed    ?           
Denied         Failed        ?
Denied         Returned    ?

Completed     Blocked        ?   
Completed     Pending        ?
Completed     Unclaimed    ?
Completed     Reversed    ?
Completed     Completed    YES            Will this always be after Processed+Completed IPN?
Completed     Failed        ?
Completed     Returned    YES
```

Comment: I've just ran into the same issue.